# SEO, better to start a new domain or it's also fine start over again on an existing one?

Tags: seo, domains

I have a site that I'm going to close or replace with new content.

Basically the site's topic is the same, but contents can't coexist for a bunch of reasons (e.g., different CMS, lack of time, different audience)

For example let's say the site was about car tuning parts, now will be about car selling adverts.

Old pages (about 5000) will all be dropped and new URLS will be created.

What should I do? Since it's a 7 year-old domain (possibly trusted by Google) I want to try to take advantage of this fact if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New domains do not carry the same clout as a site that has been around 7 years, however,  how relative the URL is to your new content is important as well.

New sites usually experience a 'honeymoon period' from Google, but it ultimately comes down to site worth (backlinks, link quality, SEO choices, etc).

I will say this: If your site currently ranks well, you may want to consider keeping the domain and doing 301 redirects from old content to retain (I've heard 1/10th) of your page rank.

I'd probably start fresh and work my way up, but it really depends on the current site's worth. Clean starts are much easier.